# tcl: How to handle closing of channel being read by fileevent readable

Tags: tcl

I need to perform some actions after input channel closing. man fileevent says:

> A file event handler is also deleted automatically whenever its channel is closed

So, if a channel was closed, the handler might not be called to handle this. I can actually see it when try to read output from a child process: the previous invocation of handler still sees [eof $fd] as false, and the next one is never called.

The only way I can imagine now is to implement some hack like a periodic watchdog which checks if the $fd is still opened, but this is quite dirty. And can I be sure that $fd will not get the same value when some other read channel is opened?

Comment: Is the answer in here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/fileevent ? (be sure to click "Show Discussion")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some clarification is needed here. When the docs say "channel is closed" it means "channel is closed in your program". In other words, until **you** call `[close]`.

If the channel is closed form the other end (for example the other side of the socket or the other end of the pipe) it is not considered closed on your side until you call `[close]` yourself. So, if the channel is closed on the other end the fileevent will be executed and `[eof]` will return true (or a read operation will error out).

I have never come across a situation where tcl detects that the channel have closed and not call the fileevent. I don't think it's possible. However, there are cases where the channel is effectively dead but not closed (usually due to network errors or the machine on the other end rebooting). For such situations you need to implement timeouts. But a timeout doesn't mean the channel have closed. It just means that you're no longer confident that the machine on the other side of the channel is still alive.

Comment: +1: Detecting closed network channels is non-trivial; if the network goes into “swallow all packets” mode, you _cannot_ detect that fact reliably (and it is indistinguishable from arbitrarily long delays). This is different from loss of the local physical layer, where detection _is_ possible (if not always trivial, of course).